# Data Binding to member property and providing design time value

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I try to understand data bindings in WPF and I could already bring some tests to work. 
But I'm stuck tight now. :(

For better organization I want to split my code into more classes and bind elements of the same Window to different classes (actually to properties of different classes).

I think I have to set the DataContext of my Window to "this" (The window itself) and use the Binding Path to specify the property to use.

```
DataContext = this;
```

-

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=_printSettings.CopyCount}"/>
```

So f.e. I want to bind to CopyCount wich is a property returning a string. 
That property belongs to the instance in the private field _printSettings of the current window. And _printSetting implements the INotifyPropertyChanged and notifies in a twoway principle.

But the label is empty during design and runtime...

I also noticed that no default values are set in the designer in my previous tests. Does anyone know an implementation? If possible without the use of a fallback value.

-MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow,Path=PrintSettings.CopyCount, FallbackValue=[0]}">
```

-MainWindow.cs

```
private PrintSettings _printSettings = new PrintSettings();
public PrintSettings PrintSettings {
   get {
      return _printSettings;
   }
}

public MainWindow()
{
   DataContext = this;
}
```

- PrintSettings.cs

> ```
> private int _copyCount = 1;
>
> //Copy count
> public string CopyCount 
> {
>     get {
>         return "" + _copyCount;
>     }
> }
> ```

-

EDIT:
added more code again

Comment: Check in output it should display whether binding succeeded or whether not. You can only bind to properties,_printSettings needs to be as well. You can alternatively set FallBackValue which will show up whenever binding fails.

Comment: yea i do the fallback test. And the fallback value is displayed. _printSetting must be a property as well? Let me try that....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding works against/through public **properties**. _printSettings is not a property. The Visual Studio "Output" window can show any binding errors you have.

Comment: Huh, yea. But specifying a Window Name in xaml breaks functionality even if the data are in public properties. Took me a couple mins to get that:) Thank y'all!

Answer (score 1):

`_printSettings` and `CopyCount` should be `public`.

If it doesnt help, then in xaml Set window Name and binding will look like this

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=YourWindowName,Path=_printSettings.CopyCount}"/>
```

or

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=YourWindowName,Path=DataContext._printSettings.CopyCount}"/>
```